# How to clone a Select element's options collection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a select element's [options collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection) in JavaScript. I want to clone the whole list of items without using jQuery. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)**

```js
let collection = document.querySelectorAll('option');
let cloned = Array.from(collection).map(option => option.cloneNode(true));
const select = document.querySelector('select');
cloned.forEach(opt=>{
  select.appendChild(opt)
})
```

```html
<select>
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option3</option>
<option>Option4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should clone and sort of data object, wont work if arrow methods are involved.

```
const clone = obj =>
  Array.isArray(obj)
    ? obj.map(item => clone(item))
    : obj instanceof Date
    ? new Date(obj.getTime())
    : obj && typeof obj === 'object'
    ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce((o, prop) => {
        o[prop] = clone(obj[prop]);
        return o;
      }, {})
    : obj;
```